# Powershell Help - Add Active Directory MemberOf to existing Script

Tags: powershell

The working PowerShell script below provides me with all the users from a specific AD Group. It also lists their Title and Department. I want to add another column that lists all of the other AD Groups they are a member of.
I added an example, the first 3 columns are from the working script the last column in yellow is what I would like to see.
I appreciate the help, my PowerShell expertise is limited.

```
$identity = 'TestGroup'
$Server = 'Test.Local'
Get-ADGroupMember –identity $identity -Server $Server -Recursive | 
Get-ADUser –Server $Server -Property Name, Title, Department | Select Name, Title, Department |
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | select name, groupscope | Export-CSV –path C:\Temp\Test15.csv –NoTypeInformation
```

[End Result Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvnTk.png)

Answer (score 2):

Don't pipe over to `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` and use a `calculated property` putting the cmdlet within the `expression` part of the object.

Values are created as arrays so use `foreach-object` along with PowerShell `$( )` operators to turn the "group name" and "scope" into colon separated values (i.e. `<group name>:<group scope>`).

Furthermore, `join` all the colon separated value pairs with a semicolon ("`;`") to concatenate all group names and group scope object pairs into one csv field.

Since this is csv data, you probably shouldn't separate any concatenated grouped pair values with a comma or import processes may interpret wrong.

#### Field Output Example

```
groupa:global;groupb;domainlocal;groupc:domainlocal
```

#### Csv Output Example

```
"Name","Title","Department","MemberOfPrimaryGroups"
"Administrator",,,"GroupA:DomainLocal;GroupB:DomainLocal;KoolAdmins:Global"
"John Doe","Systems Administrator","IT"," GroupA:DomainLocal;GroupB:DomainLocal;KoolAdmins:Global"
"Curly Moe","IT Manager","IT","GroupA:DomainLocal;GroupB:DomainLocal;KoolAdmins:Global"
```

### PowerShell

```
$identity = 'TestGroup'
$Server = 'Test.Local'

Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $identity -Server $Server -Recursive  | 
    Get-ADUser –Server $Server -Property Name, Title, Department | 
        Select-Object Name, Title, Department, @{
            N="MemberOfPrimaryGroups";
            E={(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $identity | ForEach-Object {
                "$($_.Name):$($_.GroupScope)" }) -join ";"}} | 
                    Export-CSV –path C:\Temp\Test15.csv –NoTypeInformation;
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Calculated_Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1#select-object)
- [Add a calculated property with Select-Object in PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)
- [PowerShell Operators $( ) @( ) :: &](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)
- [`-Join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1)

Comment: If you don't flatten out the group and scopes with the paired group and scope colon separated and each other paired group being semicolon separated. This way your delimiters are standard and you can import, etc. to process accordingly. Otherwise you can scale out to more csv fields e.g. after `Name`,`Title`,`department`,`GroupA`,`gScopeA`,`GroupB`,`gScopeB`...,...,...,`GroupZ`,`gScopeZ`,`GroupZa`,`gScopeZa` which seems ugly to me. Depending on your requirements for use case, but I gave you the simple one that made sense based on what I know thus far on what you need. @mugirl73

Comment: This is based on your saying "*last column in yellow is what I would like*" plus your code example includes "groupscope" field so I'm assuming you want to include those. But in one field in a csv, you cannot have an array like that, multiple values in one field have to be separated by something or it concatenates all the values to one long string in that field of a csv. A record in a csv spans across a line, so a field cannot go across more lines that the record that contains it's values. I'm assuming you need something like this, but happy to make further trivial adjustments if you ask me.